# How to put my custom number picker in a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, picker, android-dialogfragment

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >
    </net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It shows a custom picker in my app. But I want to show this picker inside a dialog.

This is my custom dialog:

```
public class NumberPickerCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Dialog")
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               }
           }).;
    return builder.create();
}
```

How can I put my picker in this dialog?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a custom layout to the dialog, to do so grab the LayoutInflater service and use it to inflate your layout.

```
public class NumberPickerCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
Context context;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // get context
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    // make dialog object
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // inflate our custom layout for the dialog to a View
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view, null);
    // inform the dialog it has a custom View
    builder.setView(view);
    // and if you need to call some method of the class
    MyCustomView myView = (MyCustomView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_id_in_my_custom_view);
    myView.doSome("stuff");
    // create the dialog from the builder then show
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Comment: In this example, what is MyCustomView? And what it contains? Thank you.

Comment: MyCustomView can be your NumberPicker(net.simonvt.widget.NumberPicker) or any other Custom classes in your layout... I just didn't know if you needed a programmatic reference to your NumberPicker object, sorry I tend to use Generics where possible :P

Comment: a pratical usage is here http://gerrit.sudoservers.com/#/c/4248/9/src/com/aokp/romcontrol/github/CommitViewerDialog.java Lines 74-92

Comment: If I use your answer, how do I could set the context variable?

Comment: it is provided as the default constructor for `public class NumberPickerCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {` _**example code updated**_

Comment: Ok, but how do I pass the context to the NumberPickerCustomDialog contructor, when I instantate a new object from this class?

Comment: in that case just get the context from the fragment itself `context = getActivity().getApplicationContext()` _**example code updated**_

Comment: Thank you. I am having some problems, yet, but your answer is very useful.